# Cannot Edit xorg.conf (permissions)

Tags: nvidia, permissions, xorg

I want to edit the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file but I can't save the file. It says "permission denied."

I have tried: `username@ubuntu:/etc/X11$ sudo gedit xorg.conf`  to no avail as i recieved:

```
(gedit:5701): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/test/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

As background, I am trying to get my nvidia-settings to be persistent following reboot.  I am also receiving this message when I start nvidia-settings:

```
`** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

(nvidia-settings:5185): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/test/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

`
so,
First how can I edit the xorg.conf file? (I could then at least put the nvidia-xconfig settings in by hand)

second, does anyone have any insight into the nvidia-settings messages I am seeing?

*please excuse the following dump, I've read these various forms for a while but never posted.

I can grab any additional info that will be helpful.

Thanks!

:/etc/X11$ ls -l

```
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 May 24 03:58 app-defaults
-rw------- 1 root root 38502400 Jun  9 18:22 core
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jul 11 17:50 cursors
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       18 Feb 18 14:59 default-display-manager
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Jul 12 07:31 fonts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14 Dec 22  2013 openbox -> ../xdg/openbox
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    17394 Dec  3  2009 rgb.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       13 May 23 22:54 X -> /usr/bin/Xorg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb 18 14:59 xinit
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jan 15  2014 xkb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2946 Jun 10 22:18 xorg.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1355 Jun 10 19:41 xorg.conf~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2946 Jul 12 01:38 xorg.conf2.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2946 Jul 12 21:52 xorg.conf.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1355 Jun 10 19:47 xorg.conf.bkup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      269 Jun  9 14:32 xorg.conf.failsafe
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Jun 10 19:41 xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     2946 Jul 12 01:40 xorg.conf.two
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2946 Jul 12 01:46 xorg.conf.two.backup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      709 Apr  1  2010 Xreset
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb 18 14:55 Xreset.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb 18 14:55 Xresources
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3730 Oct  8  2014 Xsession
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jul 11 15:54 Xsession.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      265 Jul  1  2008 Xsession.options
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb 18 14:59 xsm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      601 Feb 18 14:55 Xwrapper.config
```

:/usr/bin$ ls -l | grep nvidia

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          50 Jun 11 02:14 nvidia-bug-report.sh -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_nvidia_bug_report
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          56 Jun 11 02:14 nvidia-cuda-mps-control -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          55 Jun 11 02:14 nvidia-cuda-mps-server -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-server
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          49 Jun 11 02:14 nvidia-debugdump -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_nvidia-debugdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         270 Apr 17 11:20 nvidia-detector
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          52 Jun 11 02:14 nvidia-persistenced -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_nvidia_persistenced
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      198672 Jun 18 08:03 nvidia-settings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          43 Jun 11 02:14 nvidia-smi -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          47 Jun 11 02:14 nvidia-xconfig -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_nvidia_xconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root          99 May 21 05:28 start-nvidia-persistenced
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         109 May 21 05:28 stop-nvidia-persistenced
```

lspci

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [Quadro NVS 290] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [Quadro NVS 290] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correct the permissions for your home folder:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER
   ```
2. Don't use `sudo` without `-i` and a GUI based applications. Use

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo -i gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```

   or

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```

Comment: Be careful with the 1st command: if `shopt -s dotglob` is set it will also change hidden files and you do -not- want that.

Comment: @Rinzwind in my home folder?

Comment: Yes: ".." ".dbus" and ".gvfs" need to be root:root